# Spring MVC+JSP, get selected value from dropdown menu

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, jsp-tags

I have this page:

```
    <form method="post" action="/monitor/admin/transferDevice/${device.deviceId}" >
        <input type="submit" value="Transfer Device">
    </form>

<form:select path="users">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <c:forEach var="theUser" items="${users}">
        <form:option value="${theUser.userId}"><c:out value="${theUser.name} ${theUser.surname}"/></form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Where `users` is list of User objects.

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/transferDevice/{deviceId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String transferForDevice(@PathVariable("deviceId") int deviceId) throws Exception {

    //some logic here

    return "redirect:/admin";
}
```

So the question seems very simple but not for me. How can I pass selected User to my controller method when I press the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. So here my updated page:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="selectedUser" method="POST" action="/monitor/admin/transferDevice/${device.deviceId}" style="width: 310px;">
   <input type="submit" value="Transfer Device" style="height: 68px; width: 197px; ">
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><form:select path="userId">
                <form:option value="0" label="--- Select ---" />
                <c:forEach var="theUser" items="${users}">
                    <form:option value="${theUser.userId.toString()}"><c:out value="${theUser.name} ${theUser.surname}"/></form:option>
                </c:forEach>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
</form:form>
```

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/transferDevice/{deviceId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String transferForDevice(@PathVariable("deviceId") int deviceId, @ModelAttribute("selectedUser") User user) throws Exception {
    //so now I can use "user" from @ModelAttribute
    return "redirect:/admin";
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the form tag, does it work using this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/transferDevice/{deviceId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String transferForDevice(@PathVariable("deviceId") int deviceId, @RequestParam("users") String user) throws Exception {
```

And maybe your  form end tag should be under the form:select end tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work for me but you give me a good hint.